# Get product attribute in product view page tab

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, product-view, tabs

I want to show some product custom attribute in product view page at **TAB** like following image.

[image]

So far I've tried following

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

But it return with **NULL**

Then I tried following

```
<?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product'); ?>
```

But after using above the page goes blank and nothing will appear.

I'm making changes in following path

```
/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Tabs.php
```

***In core file just for testing purpose.*** Once It will work I'll override it.

Comment: if you want to display attributes there you can do that in description.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've sorted this by doing following

I've override the **Tabs.php**

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Tabs.php
```

In above file I've placed following code in starting

```
protected $_product = null;

function getProduct()
{
    if (!$this->_product) {
        $this->_product = Mage::registry('product');
    }
    return $this->_product;
}
```

then in `app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/viewtabs.phtml`

I've used it like following

```
<?php 
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $attribute = $_product->getData("attributecode");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in this template file (of course you should copy it to your child theme): `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml`

```
<?php 
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$att = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_id');
echo $att->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @zitix but as I've told my question is $_product = Mage::registry('current_product'); not working for me it gives me a blank page.  I've found the answer by myself check my answer.